# mapa de MapBox no ocupa el espacio del contenedor de mi modal Angular

Tags: angular, modal, mapbox, estilos, mapa

tengo el siguiente problema : ocupo una modal la cual dentro de su body estoy haciendo un display de un div con mapa el div tiene los estilos : height: 500px ; width:100% , pero al momento de abrir la modal no ocupa dichas dimensiones, necesito cubrir el background azul con todo el mapa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi codigo HTML :

`<div id="mapa-mapbox"></div>`

mi TS :

`(Mapboxgl as any).accessToken = environment.mapboxKey
this.mapa = new Mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'mapa-mapbox', 
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
center: [-74.0782322,4.5981206], // LNG-LAT
zoom: 17,`

mi CSS :

```
    `#mapa-mapbox{
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #007bff;
}`
```

Comment: Si pones  `height: 100%`, hay cambio?

Comment: no , no genera cambios , estuve inspeccionando el elemento del mapa y me di cuentael mapa esta dentro de un canvas que genera la api automáticamente con esas dimensiones que generan el mapa pequeño  y no consigo forma de modificar ese canvas

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente lo que sucede es que se esta intentando cargar el mapa antes que su contenedor en el HTML. Esto causa que el mapa se establezca con su tamaño predeterminado que es de 400x300

asegurate de inicializar el mapa luego de que su contenedor se halla cargado.

inicializa tu mapa dentro de **ngOnInit** o dentro de **ngAfterViewInit**.No se como estas usando tu modal, ya sea con materialAngular o a tu manera.

no tengo suficiente puntuación para hacer un comentario.

espero te sea de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

yo lo resolvi asi

```
setTimeout( 
               function(){
               
             map.resize();
               }
               ,3000);
```

en la funcion donde ejecuta el modal